# Issues when trying to link an HTML file to a dropdown link (no JS)

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, hyperlink, tabs, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                        <li><a href = "link1.html" >Link1</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "link2.html" >Link2</a></li>

                        <li class = "dropdown"> 
                            <a href = "link3.html" class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown"><span>Link3</span><b class = "caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href = "#subtab1">Subtab1</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "#subtab2">Subtab2</a></li>
                            </ul><!-- END: "dropdown-menu" -->      
                        </li><!-- END: "dropdown" -->
                        <li><a href = "link4.html" >Link4</a></li>

                    </ul><!-- END: "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse" -->
                </div><!-- END: "container" -->
            </div><!-- END: "container" -->
        </div><!-- END: "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" -->
```

As you can see, I've set up a navbar with multiple tabs that when individually clicked on, link to the corresponding HTML file. However, for some reason, when I click on Link3, nothing happens. I checked the name of the file - everything - but still nothing happens. I think it has to do with the li tag being located in a different spot for it, but I haven't been able to figure out the cause of this problem (I'm not using any JavaScript btw).

What do you guys think could fix this?

EDIT:

My fault. I didn't mention I'm using Bootstrap 3.2.0.

Comment: maybe another element extends over it?  have you tried setting z-index higher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using Bootstrap. If you aren't, you made something extremely similar, but this answer may not be relevant.

I think your problem is being caused due to the click function opening a menu. Try changing the "Link3" to this:

```
<a href="link3.html" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown"><span>Link3</span><b class="caret"></b></a>
```

The new code only includes an added attribute:

```
data-hover="dropdown"
```

I hope this works!